# Find files in particular directories and replace phrase

Tags: directory, search

I have a directory structure of the following

```
.
├── dir1
│   ├── a
│   │   ├── x.file
│   │   ├── y.file
│   │   └── z.file
│   ├── b
│   │   ├── x.file
│   │   ├── y.file
│   │   └── z.file
│   └── c
│       ├── x.file
│       ├── y.file
│       └── z.file
└── dir2
    ├── a
    │   ├── x.file
    │   ├── y.file
    │   └── z.file
    ├── b
    │   ├── x.file
    │   ├── y.file
    │   └── z.file
    └── c
        ├── x.file
        ├── y.file
        └── z.file
```

etc.

There are files named `x.file` in folders named `b` that I want to change a phrase in each. How can I do this without changing the other files named `x.file` in other directories and folders in fastest way possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type d -name "b" | while read Folder; do
    find "$Folder" -type f -name "a.xyz" | while read File; do
        sed -i 's/phrase1/phrase2/g' "$File"
    done
done
```